# Selecting values for time series cross-validation (Facebook Prophet)

Tags: time-series, cross-validation, prophet

Let's say I have a problem with ~400 daily obervations and I need to forecast 7 days ahead. The goal is to report how accurate such forecasts can be.
Facebook Prophet provides a convenient method `cross_validation` where you can set `initial`, `period` and `horizon`. See below a brief description from the docs:

```
This cross validation procedure can be done automatically 
for a range of historical cutoffs using the cross_validation function. 
We specify the forecast horizon (horizon), 
and then optionally the size of the initial training period (initial) 
and the spacing between cutoff dates (period). 
By default, the initial training period is set to three times the horizon, 
and cutoffs are made every half a horizon.
```

In my case, it's clear that cross-validation using `horizon=7` is what I am interested in. It's a bit less inutitive as to what values of initial and period I should choose. CV results might be very different depending on the values and selecting them in order to report the best results possible but that even sounds crappy.
Do I understand correctly, setting period to some value `X` means that you are planning to retrain your models every `X` periods and this is the only rationale behind this choice? Otherwise I cannot find any other selection criterion here.
In addition, what is the minimum amount of data to set in the initial parameter? Well, that is clearly task specific, but it might as well be that adding more data every iteration can make performance worse.

To sum up, is there any rule of thumb to determine at least more or less decent values for these parameters or probably it makes sense to stick to the defaults? In the latter case, however, there will be plenty of CV steps for each combination of hyperparameters (I am using Bayesian optimization in Optuna).